# What is prolog/epilog in Tessy?

Tags: unit-testing, embedded

I try to use [TESSY](https://www.razorcat.com/en/product-tessy.html) unit test application in my projects and now I try to be compatible with this app. I have a lot of question and doubt but one of the biggest is what is Prolog/Epilog in TESSY?
I don't have any experience with Prolog language. I think maybe it is one tools for generating test case by programming. I want generate test case instead of creating one by one and I don't know this tool can help me or no but I guess it can.
I only find TESSY user manual and my reference is this document. If you know any reference (book ,..) let me know.

Comment: Where are you reading about prolog/epilog? These terms have generic meaning which may have nothing to do with the prolog programming language.

Comment: @lurker Thanks, I read these terms in TESSY(one software for embedded software testing). What is the meaning?

Comment: a *prolog* is something that comes before a main event or text, and an *epilog* is something that comes at the end. There are many novels or stories written, for example, that have a *prolog* and an *epilog*. They come before and after the main story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is Prolog/Epilog in TESSY?

In the TESSY [user manual](https://www.razorcat.com/files/files/tessy/TESSY_4.1.x/TESSY_UserManual_41.pdf) where it refers to prolog and epilog, it is not refering to the programming language [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) but code that is executed before and after a unit test. The problem is the manual spells the words as `prolog` and `epilog` but they can also be spelled `prologue` and `epilogue`. Try querying with those alternatives and it should help.

If you look at the definition of [prologue](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prologue)

> any introductory proceeding, event, etc.:

or the definition of [epilogue](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/epilogue?s=t)

> a concluding part added to a literary work

it should make more sense.

AFAIK the words were first used with programming during the days of assembly, see: [Function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue), and carried over to unit testing. The meaning is basically the same.

Also note in the image in the manual that you can stack the prologue and epilogue, e.g

```
prolog 0
  prolog 1
    code or test
  epilogue 1
epilogue 0
```

Also while not a requirement, if there is a prologue there is typically a matching epilogue.

Sometimes it helps to look at the same idea using different terminology in a similar entity. In this case [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) is a popular unit test framework for testing Java where the words `before` and `after` are used. See: [How do I use a test fixture?](https://junit.org/junit4/faq.html#atests_2)